# Is 500 epochs too much for a CNN project?

Tags: machine-learning, python, cnn, epochs

I am working on a project where I need to train a model with a data set of 250 images. My `epochs` count is 500. Is that too much? Will it overfit?

I did this because I was following project with a data set of 40 images and the tutor used 500 `epochs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use early stopping callback to stop training when model starts overfitting. 500 epochs is too much.

create early stopping callback;

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',mode= 'min',verbose=1,patience=20,restore_best_weights=True)
```

Use the callback on model training;

```
history = model.fit(train_set,epochs= 500, validation_data = validation_set, callbacks=[es])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Dataset size is too small. So you can augment (flip, rotate, etc..) it and run your model with different numbers of epochs to check for the best accuracy.